# How to update settings in web.config File [asp.net]?

Tags: asp.net, configuration

How to update settings in `web.config` File in ASP.Net ?

```
<appSettings>
  <add key="DataSource" value="localhost\SQLEXPRESS,1433">
  <add key="InitialCatalog" value="CenTimetracker" />
  <add key="user" value="uzer" /><add key="password" value="pazz" />
  <add key="IntegratedSecurity" value="True" />
  <add key="configured" value="False" />
</appSettings>
```

I'm developing an ASP.NET website and im using web.config file to keep database connection details. as shown in the above code segment.

And i'm using following code to retrieve saved application settings at the runtime

```
string dataSource = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DataSource"].ToString();
```

How can i assign value in a textbox to web.config file? I have used following piece of code, but it doesn't save the config file.

```
ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DataSource"] = TextDataSource.Text;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Configuration myConfiguration = System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("~");
myConfiguration.AppSettings.Settings["DataSource"].Value = "some value";
myConfiguration.Save();
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: i have even tried it , but again it generates an exception by saying
"An error occurred loading a configuration file: Failed to map the path '/'. "

do i need to define the location of web.config when execute .OpenWebConfiguration("~")????

Comment: @KeizerßloodŚucker, if you have your web.config in root, this code has to work. I'm using it without any problems in my projects. Where do you keep your config file?

Comment: web.config is located at the default location as shown in following screenshot :S
http://i44.tinypic.com/1ttpxd.png

Comment: @KeizerßloodŚucker, I believe I found the solution for you. Try to run VS with administrator rights. Please, let me know whether it helped you.

Comment: thanks a lot it works fine in visual studio :) 
but once i hosted the site in a IIS server, it says "An error occured loading configuration file: Access to the path 'c:inetpub\wwwroot\CenTrackerWebService\_joekcit.tmp' is denied 
(c:inetpub\wwwroot\CenTrackerWebService\web.config)

i have changed the access rights of web.config also

Comment: @KeizerßloodŚucker, when exactly do you get this error? Every time you try to access appsettings and retrieve some values, or is problematic only this "update code"?

Comment: when retrieving there is no problem  but once update code segment is executed, that error occured

Comment: @Keizer, I just tried it on my server and works ok. I suppose there's some configuration problem at your hosting. Can you please verify in the control panel of your hosting, that you have set write permissions, for the virtual directory you're using, correctly?

Answer (score 0):

@Keizer ßloodŚucker: you can change your appsetting value as follows:

```
    Configuration myConfiguration = System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("path of webconfig file");
    myConfiguration.ConnectionStrings.ConnectionStrings["myDatabaseName"].ConnectionString = txtConnectionString.Text;
    myConfiguration.AppSettings.Settings.Add("key","value");
    myConfiguration.Save();
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to saving the configuration with Configuration.Save(), you also need to watch for file permission saving the file. You need to look at which account has been used to run your application, then add 'Modify/Write' permission for that account to the web.config. If you allow anonymous access, you normally would need to set permission the iusr_[server]. Look up these information in IIS.

Answer (score 0):

You could also load a different value on the same page where you are trying to use this value.
I use something like this in I am in debug mode.
I choose this because the method above removes any comments related to the app setting.

```
public string _path;
public string Path
{
    get
    {
        if(_path == null || _path == "")
        {
            if (System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached)
            {
                _path = "localhost\SQLEXPRESS,1433";
            }
            else
            {
                _path = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DataSource"];
            }
            return _path;
        }
        return _path;
    }
}
```